# How to include build definition in release

Tags: tfs, release

I am running end to end test for angular app. I have defined build definition in tfs server. Now I want this build to be included in my release.Shown in the pic is the build definition.[Build Definition picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04HNa.png) How Do I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand. A build definition isn't a release definition. If you want to run those activities in a release, then put them in a release. If you want to share them between a build and a release, then make a task group.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Please note my build is end to end test,I can add artifact to my build definition and ask release to take latest artifact from my build. But, is it possible to execute my build task after the release is done

Comment: Why not run the tests in the release (and not in the build)?